# ngModel to automatically check primeng checkbox

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, primeng

I have a series of checkboxes that are dynamically generated. Depending on the data, some checkboxes should be pre-selected. ngModel doesn't seem to be accomplishing this for some reason.

**Template:**

```
<div *ngFor="let value of values">
     <p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="existingValue"
                 [value]="value.value"
                 name="value-row">
     </p-checkbox>
</div>
```

**Component:**

```
...

existingValue!: string | undefined;

getValues() {
      this.apiService.getValues()
       .pipe(
           take(1),
           tap(() => // logic to determine if getValues() response has an 
                     // existing value that matches possible values 
                     // (checkboxes)
       ).subscribe(noop)
}
```

In the `tap()` my logic is determining if a certain value property exists. I shortened the logic here for examples sake. If it does exist, I'm setting `this.existingValue` to equal that property. These properties are the same as the checkbox values, but aren't when `this.existingValue` is set, the checkbox isn't actually being checked.

In instances where the box should be prechecked, the `[(ngModel)]` isn't capturing the new value of `this.existingValue` it seems

Answer (score 1):

You need a unique name, add an index to the for `*ngFor="let value of values; let i = index"` and use the index in the name `[name]="'value_row_' + i"` to make it unique. The name is used to bind the value to the form model, if they are not unique you will get conflicts.

I don't think you should use a minus sign either, I would stick to underscores, I will test it in a StackBlitz when I get to my computer.

There is quite a bit wrong with this, you are two way binding every checkbox to the same value, when any checkbox updates it will update existingValue which will update all checkboxes as they are all bound to it.

Comment: Adding a unique name didn't work for me, but I'm probably missing something else too. To explain a bit better: I have a list of `possibleValues` ie (Never, Always, Often). When I pull my data, there's a chance that there's already a populated value (ie: Often). In that tap, I have logic to determine if there's already an existing value. If there is, `this.existingValue = existingValue` and that checkbox should be checked automatically as that value already exists.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show selected values in the checkboxes from `this.existingValue`, so it's type should be an list of values : `this.existingValue : string []`, and populated from the returned values in `getValues()` method, another thing is that yo should add a lebel to show the value :

```
<label for="'value-row_' + i">{{value}}</label>
```